# Blueprint Analysis for paint, software recommendations

Tags: open-source, pdf, floor-plan

I am currently working at a retail paint store (21 years). One of the services I provide is figuring blueprints for various customers that don't know how to or do not have time. I do not charge for this service. The figuring would be to arrive at an accurate account of how much paint the walls will need per square foot. This would be total paintable wall square footage, not just floor square footage.

We are very busy at the store and I am looking for software, paid or free that would help me speed the process of figuring these plans in an accurate and efficient manner.

Most plans/blueprints are now provided in PDF format, these are the ones I'd like to use the software on.

This will run on Windows 10/11.

Example PDF: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JDmMYeWzawEwjNjCkKG4k9vxJB3ChK3_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What should this 'figuring' entail? You haven't described the desired result at all.

Comment: Also important to give good recommendations: what OS should it run on? And how much would you be willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions? What features do you need?

Comment: Hi Rob. Great question, cool problem. Please edit your question and attach a sample of the blueprints/PDFs you’re working with. And, I assume you want the software to help with measuring the dimensions im the drawings so you can arrive at some Sq. ft. number, then convert that to gallons of paint.

Comment: And you'll only get the drawings, you don't have access to the CAD model itself?

Comment: How accurate do the figures need to be? Do you need wall area per room in detail and then sum it all up. Or is just a total figure like $35k enough? Analyzing technical drawings from PDF plans is far from trivial. I just have a student working on something similar (for GD&T in manufacturing).

Comment: Total paintable square footage. At the least total paintable square footage for each area would be fine. For instance, the kitchen is 28 x 16 with 10 foot high walls? The paintable wall square footage would be 880. The dollar amount I would figure as each job is unique with varying grades of paint.

Comment: How about tracing over the image to get the dimensions? https://help.sketchup.com/en/sketchup/tracing-image